# How to set size of background image?

Tags: java, android

I need some help to set the size on android Java source for a background image, here is the code on what i want to add: `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider_bg_right);` is the line i have been added to add the background, but the image size is too small and I want to edit the size of the backgrounds.

```
switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        mTracking = true;
        mTriggered = false;
        vibrate();
        if (leftHit) {
            mCurrentSlider = mLeftSlider;
            mOtherSlider = mRightSlider;
            mThreshold = isHorizontal() ? THRESHOLD : 1.0f - THRESHOLD;
            setGrabbedState(OnTriggerListener.LEFT_HANDLE);
      ----- setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider_bg_right); -------
        } else {
            mCurrentSlider = mRightSlider;
            mOtherSlider = mLeftSlider;
            mThreshold = isHorizontal() ? 1.0f - THRESHOLD : THRESHOLD;
            setGrabbedState(OnTriggerListener.RIGHT_HANDLE);
      ------ setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slider_bg_left); -------
        }                  
        mCurrentSlider.setState(Slider.STATE_PRESSED);
        mCurrentSlider.showTarget();
        mOtherSlider.hide();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: First and foremost this is not a chat/sms forum, so use full length English words. For the question can you show your layout?

Comment: sorry for my bad english , but as this is not my main language , is dificult to write corectly , what layout you want , i want to set it without layout ,this is the default android slider , that i edited to show a background , but as this need the click of the user , i can not make it editing layouts, so i added the line that add the background , and now want to set him the size to display , how can i do it ? cheers

Answer (score 0):

try to use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(); in android in that specify needed width and height.